# Increase value in select using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to increase the page nr when my scroll from select will be at the bottom.

 demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/select-with-search-field-antd484-forked-wqnro?file=/index.js

```js
const scroll = (e) => {
  let page = 1;
  e.persist();
  const { target } = e;
  if (target.scrollTop + target.offsetHeight === target.scrollHeight) {
    page += 1;
    console.log(page);
    fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=" + page)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((body) => {
        console.log(body);
      });
  }
};
```

Scrolling i get every time `2` in `console.log(page);`, but i need to increase the value each time when i will be with scroll at the bottom of scroll section, also, when i will go back i have to decrese the number each time when the scroll will be at the top. 
 Question: What is the problem in my code and how to solve this?

Comment: The `let page = 1;` need to be outside of the `scroll` method, because now you reset it each time the `scroll` method is called. Perhaps in the components `state` ? And you should also use a flag to set and check if you are currently fetching the next page so you do not re-issue more `fetch` requests.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the page variable always starts from 1 so I think you need to have a state inside the component to save the page variable like this

```
const [page, setPage] = useState(1)

const scroll = (e) => {
  e.persist();
  const { target } = e;
  if (target.scrollTop + target.offsetHeight === target.scrollHeight) {
    setPage(prev => prev + 1)
    console.log(page);
    fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=" + page)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((body) => {
        console.log(body);
      });
  }
};
```

Comment: this will issue the fetch with the previous value of `page` because `setPage` is asynchronous.

Comment: then you can just increate page state by setPage and use page+1 in fetch function.

Answer (score 0):

Initialise the variable outside the function
Try this :

```
  let page = 1; // initialise variable outside the function
  const scroll = (e) => {
  e.persist();
  const { target } = e;
  if (target.scrollTop + target.offsetHeight === target.scrollHeight) {
    page += 1;
    console.log(page);
    fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=" + page)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((body) => {
        console.log(body);
      });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct approach would be to move the `page` variable in the local state and when the scroll reaches the end to increase the page, an let a `useEffect` handle the fetching of new data.

Assuming you are using react hooks

```js
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";


const YourComponent = () => {

  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [isFetching, setIsFetching] = useState(false);

  const scroll = useCallback(({
    target
  }) => {
    if (isFetching) return;
    if (target.scrollTop + target.offsetHeight === target.scrollHeight) {
      setPage(prevPage => prevPage + 1);
    }
  }, [isFetching]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=" + page)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((body) => {
        console.log(body);
      });
  }, [page])

  return // your render code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You call your scroll function each time the popup is scrolled: so what it does is simply resetting the page to one and add 1 at the bottom, the console prints 2 each time.

You have to save the page into a state. Nevertheless, because the setState method is asynchronous, you will need the fetch your data into a useEffect hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=" + page)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((body) => {
        console.log(body);
      });
  },[page]);
```

This hook will be execute each time your page state has been updated.

By the way, try to use ref instead of vanilla document.getElementById() to get the scrollHeight